# Efficient way to filter on column on time windows with PySpark

Tags: time, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**EDIT : I rewrote all my question trying to be clearer and added a simplified and tested code of how I proceed**

Hello,

I was wondering if there were an efficient way with PySpark to extract a dataframe from an other dataframe, by filtering on one of its column, counting distinct occurrences and all that on a time window.

I explain all of how I do it for now below with a detailed example, but when confronted with a dataset of millions of rows and thousands of distinct users, almost each steps take hours/days to finish.

I'm sure I'm doing this the wrong way as I'm new to spark so if someone could answer this question, it would really help me.

Thank you

*Creating my dataframe for the example*

```
schema = ['DateTimeStart','DateTimeEnd','User','DateTime']

df = sc.parallelize([ 
['2017-01-12 03:35:001', '2017-01-12 03:37:001','A', '2017-01-12 03:35:000'],
['2017-01-12 03:35:111', '2017-01-12 03:37:111','B', '2017-01-12 03:35:110'],
['2017-01-12 03:35:221', '2017-01-12 03:37:221','C', '2017-01-12 03:35:220'],
['2017-01-12 03:35:431', '2017-01-12 03:37:431','D', '2017-01-12 03:35:430'],
['2017-01-12 03:36:434', '2017-01-12 03:38:434','D', '2017-01-12 03:36:433'],
['2017-01-12 03:36:441', '2017-01-12 03:38:441','D', '2017-01-12 03:36:440'],
['2017-01-12 03:36:451', '2017-01-12 03:38:451','E', '2017-01-12 03:36:450'],
['2017-01-12 03:37:681', '2017-01-12 03:39:681','B', '2017-01-12 03:37:680'],
['2017-01-12 03:37:789', '2017-01-12 03:39:789','B', '2017-01-12 03:37:788'],
['2017-01-12 03:37:793', '2017-01-12 03:39:793','E', '2017-01-12 03:37:792'],
['2017-01-12 03:38:798', '2017-01-12 03:40:798','C', '2017-01-12 03:38:797'],
['2017-01-12 03:38:986', '2017-01-12 03:40:986','D', '2017-01-12 03:38:985'],
['2017-01-12 03:39:011', '2017-02-12 03:41:011','K', '2017-01-12 03:39:010'],
['2017-01-12 03:39:021', '2017-02-12 03:41:021','A', '2017-01-12 03:39:020'],
['2017-01-12 03:39:031', '2017-02-12 03:41:031','P', '2017-01-12 03:39:030'],
]).toDF(schema)

df.show()

+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|       DateTimeStart|         DateTimeEnd|User|            DateTime|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|2017-01-12 03:35:001|2017-01-12 03:37:001|   A|2017-01-12 03:35:000|
|2017-01-12 03:35:111|2017-01-12 03:37:111|   B|2017-01-12 03:35:110|
|2017-01-12 03:35:221|2017-01-12 03:37:221|   C|2017-01-12 03:35:220|
|2017-01-12 03:35:431|2017-01-12 03:37:431|   D|2017-01-12 03:35:430|
|2017-01-12 03:36:434|2017-01-12 03:38:434|   D|2017-01-12 03:36:433|
|2017-01-12 03:36:441|2017-01-12 03:38:441|   D|2017-01-12 03:36:440|
|2017-01-12 03:36:451|2017-01-12 03:38:451|   E|2017-01-12 03:36:450|
|2017-01-12 03:37:681|2017-01-12 03:39:681|   B|2017-01-12 03:37:680|
|2017-01-12 03:37:789|2017-01-12 03:39:789|   B|2017-01-12 03:37:788|
|2017-01-12 03:37:793|2017-01-12 03:39:793|   E|2017-01-12 03:37:792|
|2017-01-12 03:38:798|2017-01-12 03:40:798|   C|2017-01-12 03:38:797|
|2017-01-12 03:38:986|2017-01-12 03:40:986|   D|2017-01-12 03:38:985|
|2017-01-12 03:39:011|2017-02-12 03:41:011|   K|2017-01-12 03:39:010|
|2017-01-12 03:39:021|2017-02-12 03:41:021|   A|2017-01-12 03:39:020|
|2017-01-12 03:39:031|2017-02-12 03:41:031|   P|2017-01-12 03:39:030|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
```

*First, I create a list of time window dataframes for each user:*

```
Usernames = df.select(['User']).distinct().collect()
User_list = [str(Usernames[i]).split("'")[1] for i in range(len(Usernames))]
dfs_Users_windows = [df.filter(df.User == user).select('DateTimeStart','DateTimeEnd','User').collect() for user in User_list]
```

*Then, I loop through each list of time window dataframes previously created to get all the information for each user in each time window*

```
dfs_Users_windowed = [[df.filter(df.DateTime.between(str(dfs_Users_windows[j][i]).split("'")[1],
                                                  str(dfs_Users_windows[j][i]).split("'")[3]))
                  .groupBy(['User'])
                  .count()
                  .withColumnRenamed('User',
                                     re.sub("\.|\-|\'| |\|", '_', str(dfs_Users_windows[j][i])[87:-2])+'_neighbours')
                  .withColumnRenamed('count', 'count_window'+str(i))
                  for i in range(len(dfs_Users_windows[j]))] 
                  for j in range(len(dfs_Users_windows))]
```

*Then, I join every dataframe per user : (The way I do it may seem odd, but I found out that joining dataframe 2 by 2 and doing it repetedly is faster than successively joining the dataframes.):*

```
dfs_finals = []
for i in range(len(dfs_Users_windowed)):
list_to_loop =  dfs_Users_windowed[i]
new_list_to_loop = []
list_len = len(list_to_loop)
while list_len>1:
    if list_len%2 != 0:
        for j in range(0,list_len-1,2):
            new_list_to_loop.append(list_to_loop[j].join(list_to_loop[j+1],list_to_loop[j].columns[0],"outer"))
        new_list_to_loop.append(list_to_loop[-1])
        list_len = len(new_list_to_loop)
        list_to_loop = new_list_to_loop
        new_list_to_loop = []
    else:
        for j in range(0,list_len,2):
            new_list_to_loop.append(list_to_loop[j].join(list_to_loop[j+1],list_to_loop[j].columns[0],"outer"))
        list_len = len(new_list_to_loop)
        list_to_loop = new_list_to_loop
        new_list_to_loop = []
dfs_finals.append(list_to_loop)
```

*Then, I just remove the "null" values introduced by the outer join*

```
dfs_finals_clean = [dfs_finals[i][0].na.fill(0) for i in range(len(dfs_finals))]
```

*And as a result I get what I expect. Example on user E:*

```
dfs_finals_clean[4].show()

+------------+-------------+-------------+
|E_neighbours|count_window0|count_window1|
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|           A|            0|            1|
|           B|            2|            0|
|           C|            0|            1|
|           D|            0|            1|
|           E|            1|            0|
|           K|            0|            1|
|           P|            0|            1|
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you've tried?

Comment: @sailesh I've rewrote all of my question and added a simplified but working example of how i proceed, thanks for your time

Comment: I can give you an idea that I'm sure it works. Try creating a duplicate dataframe and join both on a condition where time diff is < 24 hours and group by on neighbours and collect_set the neighbours of duplicate dataframe.

Comment: @sailesh This solution didn't even cross my mind, i'll try it and update my results here, thanks

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions. I'll probably find some time to describe some more about it.

Comment: @sailesh I've never used collect_set so if you could detail your idea a bit, it would further help me

Comment: I'll try this today evening.